# JavaFX : Gluon library with ANT or convert JavaFX-Ant project to JavafX-Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, ant, gluon

I have a JavafX project which I would like to export for Ipad only. I found out that the Gluon framework can do that for me. Unfortunately, the JavaFX project I have uses Ant, not Gradle as shown in the Gluon docs.

**Is there any way I can put the Gluon dependency in the Ant task and generate the IOS output executable?** If not, then is it possible to convert this project into a Gradle Project.

Please note I am using Ubuntu Linux. I don't know what is required to create Ipad executables. It is possible that my understanding of this might be wrong as I have not dealt with Mac systems before.

Here is the build.xml for ant :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<anttasks:AntTask xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:anttasks="http://org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt/1.0" buildDirectory="${project}/build" cssToBin="true">
  <deploy packagingFormat="exe">
    <application name="Test" mainclass="application.Main" version="1.0"/>
    <info title="Frontend" vendor="NAME"/>
  </deploy>
  <signjar/>
</anttasks:AntTask>
```

That's all I have in the entire project, other are just Java files I have created myself. Any help would be nice. Thank you.

*Update*

As per the answer received, I created a Gradle project and moved the files there. After that I added the libraries for Gluon from [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/free-trials/), but I keep getting this error :

```
Error:(14, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'androidRuntime()'!

Possible causes could be:  
  - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent (<a href="open_gradle_settings">Fix Gradle settings</a>)
  - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method (<a href="apply_gradle_plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>)
  - or there is a mistake in a build script (<a href="goto_source">Goto source</a>)
```

[image]

*Update-2*

So, what I finally did was install the Gluon plugin for Intellij Idea, and then created a Gluon project. As suggested on the webpage, I have added ANDROID_HOME parameter and the directory point to android-sdk for Linux. Still, when I call run the program, I keep getting the error:

```
Error:Android Source Generator: [GluonBasicProject] Android SDK is not specified
```

My gradle.properties looks like this :

```
gradlePropertiesProp=gradlePropertiesValue
systemProjectProp=shouldBeOverWrittenBySystemProp
envProjectProp=shouldBeOverWrittenByEnvProp
systemProp.system=systemValue
ANDROID_HOME=/home/akshay/Downloads/android-sdk-linux
```

Please note, when creating this project I had selected default gradle-wrapper, and I found 4 gradle distributions on my system, so I updated the ANDROId_HOME value in all four of them.

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running on a Mac? You will need it to create the iPad apps...

Comment: @JoséPereda : I don't have a MAC, but I will create a VM of Mac OS, and do stuff in it. Can you tell me how to deal with this problem on a Mac then?

Comment: That won't work, as far as I know. Anyway, I'll answer your question

Comment: @JoséPereda : My colleague has a Mac, we will find a Mac system if necessary. Kindly let me know how to proceed when you have time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a Gradle project, and add your Java/JavaFX sources. Ant won't be required, and gradle will manage everything for you.

To make things easier, Gluon has a [plugin](http://gluonhq.com/products/tools/) for the major IDEs (NetBeans, IntelliJ and Eclipse). You just need to install that plugin and it will allow creating a simple gradle project with all that you need to add your own sources and build it and deploy it on desktop, Android and iOS devices.

You can find several post about installing the plugin and creating projects from the scratch on Gluon's site:

- [NetBeans](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-plugin-for-netbeans/)
- [IntelliJ](http://gluonhq.com/the-new-gluon-plugin-for-intellij-idea/)
- [Eclipse](http://gluonhq.com/the-new-gluon-plugin-for-eclipse/)

In order to do this, you need some [prerequisites](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#anchor-1). The most critical in your case will be having a Mac in order to deploy to iPhone/iPad. The rest is software required and minor configuration.

Notice that using Gradle you will have to work with `Tasks`.

You can run from command line (as well as from your IDE) the task you require:

```
./gradlew clean build
./gradlew run
./gradlew androidInstall
./gradlew launchIOSDevice
...
```

Note that for deploying to iOS you will need some [settings](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_ios_4) on the build script. Also, read [this](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_building_and_running) about Apple free provisioning.

Comment: I added Java sources, now when I try to add the Gluon library, I get error. I have updated my main post. Can you please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Please, post your build.gradle file. Once you add your sources you should be able to run on your desktop from the Gradle panel (on the right), selecting the `run` task. You need to install Android sdk first and set `ANDROID_HOME` to deploy to Android.

Comment: I have updated the post, and have also set ANDROID_HOME parameter. Still, I am not able to run the project. Can you kindly have a look at the main post. Thank you.  :-)

Comment: You can update the plugin to 1.0.7 version (check here for latest [update(https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin)). Also check the Android sdk, you need at least platform-21, though 23 is recommended, including building tools.

Comment: Ok. I created a new project and skipped Android. Anyways, my interest lies in creating executable for IOS. Now, I have a project running on Intellijd Idea and I had selected IOS. The updated build.gradle : http://pastebin.com/jwgHXAUc  . Now, where can I find the settings to generate files for IOS? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Update this: `'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.7'`. The iOS prerequisites are already at the end of my answer.

Comment: Okay. Just one last thing, thank you very much. I tried for android as well, by updating the build.gradle like http://pastebin.com/KDCB88h1 . The gradle build is successful, but it complains that there is no Android device attached. I would like to generate an APK, instead of directly running. Is there any command for the same? Kindly let me know. Thanks a  lot. :-)

Comment: You can use the `android` task for that, and find the resulting Apk in the builds directory under JavaFXPorts folder

Comment: What do you mean by android task? Whenever I am running the gradle commands, I can see an APK in javaFXPorts, but it has a parse-error. I even set debuggable to false in Manifest, still the same thing.

Comment: Run `./gradlew android` on command line, and if you have any issue post the stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you for bringing me till here, but even if I give command ./gradlew android, I get Build successful, but when I try to install APK, I get parse-error. I have unknown sources allowed.. I will post a new question for this tomorrow morning along with an executable for IOS. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I am troubling you a lot, but you were right, as soon as I moved the contents to resources, the APK got installed, but it's not loading any static content. I hope you don't mind checking this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360186/javafx-gluon-html-file-not-loaded-from-java-code-in-apk . Thanks a lot again. :-)