# JavaFX, Gluon : HTML file not loaded from Java code in APK

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon

I have a Gluon JavafX project on Intellij Idea after installing Gluon plugin, in which I am loading some static HTML files in JavaFX's Webkit browser.

Now, when I start the JavaFX application directly, I can see the HTML being loaded, but when I create the APK, I don't see the HTML being loaded. I tried two paths i.e `html/index.html` and `index.html`, but for both the APK didn't show me anything in the app, it just loads a black screen.

As per the previous question I had about Gluon, I have moved static content in resources directory. This increased the size of APK a lot and that was a confirmation that the static content is inside the APK.

Here is the Main class :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Rewe - Frontend");
    java.net.CookieManager manager = new java.net.CookieManager();
    java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

    myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
    scene = new Scene(myBrowser, 1080, 1920);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.show();
```

}

Mybrowser.Java :

```
public class MyBrowser extends Region {

    final String hellohtml = "index.html";

    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
public MyBrowser() {
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("app", this);
            }
        });

        URL urlHello = getClass().getResource(hellohtml);

        webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());
        webView.setPrefSize(1080, 1920);
        webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
}
```

Here is the screenshot showing static files in appropriate folders and Java files as well :

[image]

Then why is that when I open the APK I just see a black screen. I just put "Hello world" in `body` of `index.html`, even that is not shown. Any help would be nice. Thank you.

*Update*

Error log with adb :

```
: QuantumRenderer: shutdown
02-12 12:49:24.539 13109 13132 W System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err:    at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher$1.run(DalvikLauncher.java:188)
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$137(LauncherImpl.java:182)
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$1(LauncherImpl.java)
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err:    ... 1 more
02-12 12:49:24.540 13109 13132 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.net.URL.toExternalForm()' on a null object reference
02-12 12:49:24.541 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.rewetest.MyBrowser.<init>(MyBrowser.java:69)
02-12 12:49:24.541 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.rewetest.Main.start(Main.java:30)
02-12 12:49:24.541 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$144(LauncherImpl.java:863)
02-12 12:49:24.541 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$8(LauncherImpl.java)
02-12 12:49:24.541 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
02-12 12:49:24.541 13109 13132 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$157(PlatformImpl.java:326)
```

Comment: Have you tried on your desktop? If it doesn't work on Desktop it is because a known bug.

Comment: @JoséPereda : When I have just a JavaFX project, without Gluon, then it works fine. Now when I load the Project as an application, I just get an error, Android SDK not specified. Although I have specified in jfxMobiel{android{ //here}} .

Comment: @JoséPereda : I can give you the Java files for both Main and MyBrowser. Can you just trying with an html of your own, to see what paths work?

Comment: Can you run it on desktop or not? In order to run on Android, first it should be running on desktop as well. Just select the `run` task on the Gradle tab, and see if works. If not, fix the issues first.

Comment: I can run on desktop.. No problem.

Comment: ok, and on Android you have a black screen? Then you have to find out the reason for that. With your device connected, on command line go to Android sdk/platform-tools and run `./adb logcat -v threadtime` and try to find an exception in the output of your application.

Comment: @JoséPereda : I have updated my main post to include the error log. Seems like a path problem, how can I define the index.html. As stated in the main post, I tried two variations, neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("index.html").toExternalForm());
```

you need to put the resources in the same package as that class:

```
src/main/resources/com/<your package>
```

or if you want to put it in a different folder, use "/" as root of the resources:

```
webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/html/index.html").toExternalForm());
```

This will solve the NPE.

I don't see it in your code, but I take that you are adding the `WebView` to the scene:

```
public MyBrowser() {
     ...
     getChildren().add(webView);
}
```

Comment: If I put it in src/java/resources/com/package-name like before where you said that you cannot see the Java files, then the APK does not pick it up. I have to put it in src/main/resources to be picked up by APK. I have the constructor you mentioned in the code, no problem on that front.